# Android: Access function of an external package

Tags: android, android-intent, package, clock

I am trying to figure out how access a function in an external program. I currently have this:

```
 ComponentName cn1 = new ComponentName("com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl");
```

Which will launch the HTC world clock. I would like it, instead of launching the main program, launch the night mode function of the app or full screen clock function of the app. Is it possible?

The picture below shows the ui button that launches the function I would like to launch programmatically [image]y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HTC world clock program would launch night mode activity when receive other intent or this intent with extra parameter, it is possible.
But as you don't know the implement of HTC world clock, so I think it is hard and impossible.

Comment: If only I could find the source HTC worldclock source code online!